# Некорректная работа multiple transclude компонента на Angularjs 1.6.1

Tags: angularjs

При использовании multiple transclude компонента в Angularjs приложении наблюдается странное поведение:
изменения в моделях первого слота не видны в контроллере.

[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/Lpveophe/1/)

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="testController">

<script type="text/ng-template" id="component-template.html">
<div style="color:red;" ng-transclude="heading">
</div>
<div style="color:blue;" ng-transclude="body">
</div>
</script>

Example1
<input ng-model="example1Model"/>

<test-component>
    <panel-heading>
      Example2
      <input ng-model="example2Model"/>
    </panel-heading>
    <panel-body>
    Example1Result:{{example1Model}}<br/>
    Example2Result:{{example2Model}}
    </panel-body>
</test-component>
</div>

<script>
angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller("testController", function ($scope, $location) {

})
.component("testComponent", {
    templateUrl: "component-template.html",
    transclude: {
        heading: "panelHeading",
        body: "panelBody"
    },
    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {        
        this.$doCheck = function () {

           //do anything
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Подскажите, почему не работает binding модели "example2Model", хотя binding модели "example1Model" работает корректно?

Comment: а с чего вы взяли что такой код будет работать, вы создаёте директиву, которая должна грузить код из файла `component-template.html`, а самого файла нет, темплэйты так не работают (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script). Замените `<test-component>` на обычный `<div>` и модель работает корректно

Comment: Данный код является примером, при этом строка "<script type="text/ng-template" id="component-template.html">" указывает ангуляру, что шаблон должен браться из текущей области HTML. В документации, к которой Вы обращаетесь (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script), есть пример в подтверждение описанного мною поведения. В полной версии приложения код файла component-template.html расположен отдельно, ситуация при этом аналогичная.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задал аналогичный вопрос на английской версии, предложили рабочее решение:

Чтобы пример заработал, необходимо заменить example2Model на o.example2Model и изменить код контроллера:

```
.controller("testController", function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.o = {};
    $scope.o.example2Model = '';
})
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41561988/strange-behavior-using-multiple-transclude-component-in-angularjs-1-6-1